# How to inject variable to local workfolder on Jenkins?

Tags: tfs, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use TFS with Jenkins and I want to create a job that sets its working folder to workspaces/%COMPUTERNAME%/. When I set %COMPUTERNAME% or ${COMPUTERNAME} it just creates a folder with them. I expected Jenkins to replace it by actual machine name.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for injection of variable [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)
hope it helps!